# How to move all files of a folder to another folder in ssh console?

Tags: linux, ssh

I have tree structure like in the same level

- public_html
- connection

& inside the public_html I have

- conn

so I want to move all the files & folder of folder public_html/conn to connection folder which is in the level of public_html,so which exact command of ssh can give me the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the folder `conn` to be inside `connection`:

```
mv -i public_html/conn/ connection
```

Alternatively, if you want the files inside `conn`, but not the `conn` folder itself, to be inside `connection`:

```
mv -i public_html/conn/* connection
mv -i public_html/conn/.* connection
```

Would definitely suggest doing `man mv` beforehand to avoid making a mistake.